Nonparametric extrema hypothesis test based on ranks
Does there exist a non-parametric test testing the following hypothesis:
given $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and their ranking $Y$ in $\mathbb{N}$ answer:
$H_0:$ there is no minimum or maximum (extrema) in the set of points
$H_a:$ there is either a minimum or maximum  (extrema) in the set of points
i.e. does there exist a test that is able to differentiate these 2 pictures:
on this picture there is a well definined minimum and this fact is supported by neighboring points (low ranks are clustered nearby)

on this picture there no minimum, the points are simply random (low ranked points are not grouped nearby and are scattered)

ideally the test should work in more than 1-D, be non-parametric and rank-only based. make no assumptions about the shape of underlying data


If there is one (a local but noisy minimum or maximum), can there be more than one (like a W shape or N shape, say), or is it that it can only have one - either a local noisy min or a local noisy max? 2. Can the extreme be up one end -- for example, one that would look like  __⁄ ?


One can consider either way if construction of such a test will be easier. I am more interested in methodology: once i see it, i think i will be able to adapt it to either case.
